# Add to an array from within a loop using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am having a few problems adding to an array from within a loop.
It only adds the last results to the array and loses the previous 9 sets.

I think I have to create a new array inside of the loop and then add the new one to the previous. I'm just not sure how I go about doing that.

```
array = Array.new

10.times do
  array2 = Array.new
  pagenum = 0
  results = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}#{pagenum}"))
  results.css("div").each do |div|
    array.push div.inner_text
  end
  pagenum + 10
  array.concat(array2)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching same page (`0`) 10 times.

```
10.times do
  ...
  pagenum = 0 # <--------
  results = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}#{pagenum}"))
  ...
end
```

Try following:

```
array = Array.new
10.times do |pagenum|
  results = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}#{pagenum}"))
  array += results.css("div").map(&:inner_text)
end
```

Comment: at the bottom of the loop I add 10 to the page number each time?

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins, `pagenum + 10` does not change the value of `pagenum`. Maybe it's typo of `pagenum += 10`. Even though that typo is fixed, `pagenum` is reset to 0 by `pagenum = 0`.